# The Witch-king vs Gandalf

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf, nazgul

I've been reading answers to this question but none of them answer it. Who is stronger in magic and sword-fight? Who would win? People say Gandalf is equal to Sauron, but I find that extremely hard to believe.

While the Witch-king is said to be the strongest and most fierce of Sauron's servants, he was defeated by Aragorn. The Witch-king cannot be killed by man, but Gandalf isn't a man. If the Witch-king is so strong Tolkien and Peter Jackson did a very lousy job at showing his power. They make him seem like a normal man, yet he's the most powerful servant of Sauron. If the Witch-king can be defeated by Gandalf or almost anyone with magic powers (which it seems) then why even create such a "a powerful being yet defeated almost by anyone"? Logic dictates that "the evil servant will always defeat the hero".

Comment: "While the with king is said to be the strongest and most fierce of saurons servants,he got defeated by Aragorn." Did I miss something?

Comment: fellowship of the ring

Comment: Ohhh, you mean Weathertop. Well, I would not exactly call that "defeated", but I get now what you mean.

Comment: I don't understand who you're quoting in those quotations of yours :P

Comment: What's the "this question" in the first sentence?

Comment: reading answers to the question who would win between gandalf vs the witch king

Comment: I used to ask "Who would win in a fight, a tiger or a shark?" Then I turned five and realized it was a stupid question.

Comment: The breaking of Gandalf's staff by the Witch King is probably my least favorite of the many travesties in the RotK Special Edition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I always found these kind of questions to be silly, hypothetically pitting Gandalf against the Witch King of Angmar seems a bit trivial and dumbs down Tolkien's writing. That being said, the whole "being killed by no man" prophecy aside, Gandalf was a Maiar, and he actually fought the Nazgûl on Weathertop for an entire night. Frodo saw this from afar and asked Aragorn what all that light was, but Aragorn didn't know it was actually Gandalf fighting the nine. Although he didn't kill them he fought them the entire night and escaped. They even felt his presence before in day but they felt his power and were to scared to face him with the sun out.

> "I galloped to Weathertop like a gale, and I reached it before sundown on my second day from Bree — and they were there before me. They drew away from me, for they felt the coming of my anger and they dared not face it while the Sun was in the sky. But they closed round at night, and I was besieged on the hill-top, in the old ring of Amon Sûl. I was hard put to it indeed: such light and flame cannot have been seen on Weathertop since the war-beacons of old."

Comment: Excellent answer. I've been wondering about this lately as in the extended movies, the Witch King simply seems to raise is weapon, do a bit of magic and utterly shatters Gandalf's staff in Minas Tirith. I believe it was at this point that Theoden arrived and he had to leave Gandalf to organize the battle with the new enemies. I figured if the Witch King was just a man (having received one of the rings of power) then how could he do this to a Maiar? It doesn't make sense to me so I'm reading as much as I can to learn more.

Comment: Tolkein -> Tolkien